# powershell without prompts and 1 file

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Thank you for reading.  This Current Power Shell when run prompts for a Start Date, then asks for how many days back.  It then executes a stored Procedure, and based on the information creates a X number of CSV's in the folder defined...

What I want to do is NOT prompt, The Start Date Being YESTERDAY, and the End day being 7 Days agi, and keep the results to one file instead of 7..

Here is the Code, if I can imposition you to please leave an updated code that would be wonderful.  Thank you so much for your time!!!

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
$connString = "Data Source=MYSQL;Initial Catalog=ACCESSCONTROL;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$FromDate = Read-Host "Enter Date of to Start (YYYY-MM-DD)"
$NumOfDates = Read-Host "Enter Number of Days (This will also include the Date above)"
$QueryText = "exec UDO_VW_ExportView_HISTORY '2010-01-01'"

$DTFromDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($FromDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
$DTEndDate = $DTFromDate.AddDays($NumOfDates - 1)

while ($DTFromDate -le $DTEndDate) {

  $SqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connString
  $SqlCommand = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
  $SqlCommand.CommandText = "EXEC UDO_VW_ExportView_HISTORY @FromDate"

  #Add parameters to pass values to the stored procedure

  $SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", $FromDate) | Out-Null
  $DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter       
  $SqlCommand
  $dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
  Write-Host $DataAdapter.Fill($dataset) ' records have been exported as a CSV file'
  $dataset.Tables[0] | Export-CSV D:\_#Scripts\Daily_Export_HISTORY\Daily_Report_Csv\MyReport.csv  -NoTypeInformation -Force
  Write-Host 'New report D:\_#Scripts\Daily_Export_HISTORY\Daily_Report_Csv\MyReport.csv has been successfully generated'
  (gc D:\_#Scripts\Daily_Export_HISTORY\Daily_Report_csv\MyReport.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"""', '"'} | out-file D:\_#Scripts\Daily_Export_HISTORY\Daily_Report_csv\Daily_Report_For_$FromDate.csv -Fo -En ascii
  Remove-Item D:\_#Scripts\Daily_Export_HISTORY\Daily_Report_csv\MyReport.csv 

  $DTFromDate = $DTFRomDate.AddDays(1)
  $FromDate = $DTFromDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
}

Invoke-item D:\_#Scripts\Daily_Export_HISTORY\Daily_Report_csv|Sort parent
```

Comment: What have you tried? There's a couple variable where you are being asked for the values you want to be permanent. You should start with setting those.

Comment: Why ask for yesterday's date when you can simply do `$DTFromDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date` (same for 7 days ago)